# schema.org duplicate content handling

Tags: html, schema.org, duplicate-content

I'm about to add the code from schema.org for reviews and local businesses. The question I  have is: if I have a browse section, should I add the schema code to that as well, meaning I would have two instances on the site per business? Or should I only do a schema on the canonical content?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the schema code to the non-canonical sections as well, specifying the canonical reference with `itemprop="url"` and the link to it.